# Prevent Cleaner apps from deleting my apps files

Tags: android, filesystems

**What I Have**

I have an app which needs to store some of its important files in the SD card and Internal memory with some random names.

**The Problem**

Some cleaner apps like CCleaner are detecting these files as junk files and deleting them. How can I solve this problem? Can I somehow prevent the cleaner apps from detecting these important files as junks?

Answer (score 1):

Are they really junk? If not then try saving it following the best practices using the developer site. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal
Happy Coding!

Comment: No they are not junk files at all. But have random names with random extension. That's the business logic of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You rename your file to *.jet. 
App cleaner will not delete this file type.